# Could not load image into Google drive using REST api v3(Simple Upload) and qt5.9

Tags: c++, qt, rest, drive

I use the QT5.9 and the google REST API to work with google drive.
I'm trying to download an image using "simple upload". I receive an error: "Error transferring https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3?uploadType=media - server replied: Not Found"

Using the Multipart Upload option, there are no problems. The image is loaded.

Please help me to find the error when using "simple upload".

**[Multipart Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload) code(successfully)**

```
void MainWindow::upload()
{
    QUrl url("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart");
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);

    QString bound = "foo_bar_baz";
    QByteArray data(QString("--"+bound+"\r\n").toLatin1());
    data.append("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n");
    data.append("{\"name\":\"1\"}\r\n");
    data.append("--"+bound+"\r\n");
    data.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n");

    QFile file("1.jpg");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    data.append(file.readAll());
    data.append("\r\n");
    data.append("--"+bound+"--\r\n");

    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QString("multipart/related;boundary="+bound).toLatin1());
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, 
    QString::number(data.length()).toLatin1());
    QString bearer = "Bearer " + google.token();
    request.setRawHeader(QString("Authorization").toLatin1(),bearer.toLatin1());
    QNetworkAccessManager *am = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    am->post(request,data);
}
```

**[Simple Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/simple-upload)**(Error transferring  server replied: Not Found")

```
void MainWindow::upload()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);


    QString imagePath("1.jpg");

    QFile file(imagePath);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QByteArray data;
    data.append("\r\n\r\n");
    data.append(file.readAll());
    file.close();


    QNetworkRequest request;
    QUrl urlToUpload("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3?uploadType=media");
    request.setUrl(urlToUpload);

    QString bearer = "Bearer " + google.token();
    qDebug() <<  bearer;
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,QString("image/jpeg").toLatin1());
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader,QString::number(data.length()).toLatin1());
    request.setRawHeader(QString("Authorization").toLatin1(), bearer.toLatin1());
    QNetworkReply *reply   =  manager->post(request,data);
}
```

Comment: Isn't "files" missing in the URL after v3?

Comment: I add "files" in the URL after v3. Image uploaded.  But when you view this file, an error occurs: the file is corrupted.

It's strange that in the [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/simple-upload)  query there is no "files"